# Quadratic Function whose graph contains the points:

Tags: linear-algebra

A quadratic function is a function of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$ where a, b, and c are constants. Given any 3 points in the plane, there is exactly one quadratic function whose graph contains these points.

Find the quadratic function whose graph contains the points (−4,21), (−3,11), and (0,5).

Comment: What ideas have you come up with?

Comment: I kind of guess and checked.. but couldn't come up with a solution. This is my first time taking a linear algebra class and a solution would be helpful as a I have a ton of these questiosn..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Let $\;y=ax^2+bx+c;$ be the wanted quadratic, then

$$\begin{align*}21&=a\cdot (-4)^2+b\cdot(-4)+c\iff&16a-4b+c=21\\
11&=a\cdot (-3)^2+b\cdot(-3)+c\iff&9a-3b+c=11\\
5&=a\cdot (0)^2+b\cdot(0)+c\iff&c=5\end{align*}$$

Now solve the above equations for $\;a,b\;$ ...

Comment: Nice! thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

for point $(-4,21)$ we have $$a(-4)^2+b(-4)+c=21$$
for other 2 points we have 2 equations. solve system of 3 equations
 $$ 
9a-3b+c=11
$$
$$c=5$$
$$16a-4b+c=21$$

Answer (score 0):

When you take the equation $y=ax^2+bx+c$ and plug in the values $(x,y)=(-4,21)$, $(-3,11)$ and $(0,5)$, you get three equations in three unknowns:

$$\begin{align}
21&=16a-4b+c\\
11&=9a-3b+c\\
5&=c\\
\end{align}$$

This very easily becomes two equations in two unknowns:

$$\begin{align}
16&=16a-4b\\
6&=9a-3b\\
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from there?